# How to load image to mobile phone storage using Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I should: To save an image to mobile phone storage

My attempt and code:

```
/***************************SAVE TO STORAGE ********************************/

private String saveImage(Bitmap image) {
    String savedImagePath = null;

    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + "FILE_NAME" + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = new File(            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            + "/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        success = storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
        savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Add the image to the system gallery
        galleryAddPic(savedImagePath);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "IMAGE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return savedImagePath;
}

private void galleryAddPic(String imagePath) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(imagePath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    getContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

/***************************SAVE TO STORAGE ********************************/
```

in button listener method

```
  fabLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String URLIMAGE = imgPos;
            Glide.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                    .load(URLIMAGE)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super
                                Bitmap> glideAnimation)  {

                            saveImage(resource);

                            try {
                                WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).setBitmap(resource);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I wrote my code using documentation, but unfortunately it does not work.
When I click on the button, image does not load in storage of my mobile phone.

Comment: Did you give your app the permission to access the storage? Please add your Manifest

Comment: yes, I've given

Comment: `but unfortunately it does not work` What happens exactly? What are the logs? Do you get any error? Please be more specific